# Increment columns of a data frame in a for loop in R

Tags: database, loops, increment, breakpoints, autoregressive-models

For example, I have the closing prices for these companies in a data frame e.g., one column has the closing prices for apple, then the next column has the closing prices for microsoft and so on.

Now I want to calculate the break points for each of these companies. I am going to use the function breakpoints from the package `strucchange`:

```
bps<-breakpoints(APPLE ~ lag(APPLE,k=1),...)
```

Where the formula is an AR(1) as you can see.

My question is: How can I put this formula in a loop in order to compute this function for every company?